# How can I get the value of a number thats supposedly to show in a table in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

I need whatever value that shows inn the table td sub total to show in the amount of the script. The aim is to process the total subtotal amount in the inline code of the payment merchant. if there is a code to capture such data with html too it would be aprreciated

```js
<script src="https://api.ravepay.co/flwv3-pug/getpaidx/api/flwpbf-inline.js"></script>
    <button type="button" onClick="payWithRave()">Pay Now</button>
</form>

<script>
    const API_publicKey = "FLWPUBK-7991a166b25a84cbfb0cdc0deaa78c1f-X";
var selector = document.getElementsByClassName()
    function payWithRave() {
        var x = getpaidSetup({
            PBFPubKey: API_publicKey,
            customer_email: "user@example.com",
            amount: 20,
            customer_phone: "234099940409",
            currency: "NGN",
            txref: "rave-123456",
            meta: [{
                metaname: "flightID",
                metavalue: "AP1234"
            }],
            onclose: function() {},
            callback: function(response) {
                var txref = response.data.txRef; // collect txRef returned and pass to a                    server page to complete status check.
                console.log("This is the response returned after a charge", response);
                if (
                    response.data.chargeResponseCode == "00" ||
                    response.data.chargeResponseCode == "0"
                ) {
                    // redirect to a success page
                } else {
                    // redirect to a failure page.
                }

                x.close(); // use this to close the modal immediately after payment.
            }
        });
    }
```

```html
<div class='sora_order'>
<table>
<tbody>
<tr>
<th>Selected Payment Method</th>
<td class='soramethodsuccess'/>
</tr>
<tr>
<th>Order ID</th>
<td class='soraorderidsuccess'/>
</tr>
<tr>
<th>Order date</th>
<td class='soraorderdate'>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<th>Your Subtotal</th>
<td class='soratotalsuccess'> </td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
  </div>
 
 <form>
   
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can assign an id to that element, then get the innerText value of that element:

```
<td id="subtotal" class='soratotalsuccess'>10</td>

<script>
const amount = document.getElementById("subtotal").textContent
</script>
```

You can also do it by className, but it will be less efficient

```
document.getElementsByClassName("soratotalsuccess")[0].textContent
```